# x-webkit-speech removal from input

Tags: input, attributes, webkit

This should be simple but alas it dosn't appear to be so.

I don't want the mic to show up in my input box

I have small input put boxes and chrome likes to add "x-webkit-speech" 
Is there a way I can control this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speech should be disabled by default, you can add `x-webkit-speech` to your `input` to provide speech to text functionality.  If you want to move the microphone image outside of the `input` box, look at this http://www.phpied.com/x-webkit-speech-input-and-textareas/